# Fix problematic number formatting

Tags: regex, libreoffice-calc

In a spreadsheet I have several columns which had the following number format: `233,95`. I have replaced all commas with dots, to `233.95`, but it turns out that this was not such a good idea as there are many values over 1000 which have already a dot in it, like `1.233.95`.

I cannot undo the first replace action anymore with a normal search and replace. Making a new export and starting over will waste hours of work on this table. There are no numbers bigger than 10.000.

Is there an easy way to fix `1.233.95` to `1233.95`? It should not mess up numbers like `1200` and `0.9`.

Answer (score 1):

I find regex difficult, and would do it like this:

In excel-syntax, I can provide you the answer. It is often the same or very similar in libre. First transfer the data to Sheet2.

In cell B2 (assuming you want data in cell B2 of course ;) ).

```
=text(substitute(Sheet2!B2,".","")/100;"##,###.00")
```

in this, i assume that you have trailing zeros (for example, it is displayed as 1.000.00 as opposed to simply 1.000)

Finally you might want to copy --> paste as values to make it persistent.

Comment: Thanks! It's simpler, but you gave me the hint I needed: `=SUBSTITUTE(B2,".","")/100`

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. For this number it does, but it messes up numbers like 260 or 0.3.

Comment: ok. that means you dont have trailing zeros :( i have no easy fix for that. You might want to do it with regex as @Harvinder outlines below... an alternative is to count the number of dots in the string (see for example http://en.kioskea.net/faq/5768-excel-how-to-count-a-letter-s-occurences-within-a-cell) and then use if-clauses to take account for the diffent cases.

Comment: I'm going to fix this with PHP.

Comment: okay. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing initially you did something like: `^([:digit:]*),([:digit:]*)$` --> `$1\.$2`, this time you'll do something like: `^([:digit:]*)\.([:digit:]*)\.([:digit:]*)$` --> `$1$2\.$3`

**Note:** I'm not sure if you need to escape the `.` in the replace expression. Maybe all you need is `$1$2.$3`